# Создаю новый проект в юнити или захожу на старый сразу выскакивает ошибка

Tags: unity3d-android

при созданий проекта предлагают запустить его в безопасном режиме и потом вот такая ошибка internal build system error. Build Program exited with code -1073741819 или просто пустая.Я пробивал переустанавливать юнити едитор,юнити хаб, запускал от имени администратора проблема сохраняеться.